# FactoryBeanNotInitializedException while autowire EntityManager into service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, autowired

**Question:** From where to start when trying to resolve `FactoryBeanNotInitializedException` exception while injecting `EntityManager` into service?

**Code:**

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    ....
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet
```

Comment: Is EntityManager the only Autowired field in that class?

Comment: Please add more context. Post the full stack trace. What creates your `MyService` bean (where's your component scan)? What creates your `EntityManager` bean (where's the factory bean)?

Comment: @WojtekO.no, there are a bunch of other autowires, which works good

Comment: how you have defined entityManager is it in xml or anotation, share that code also

Comment: @Panther need time to find out where it's defined

Answer (score 2):

try 
*@PersistenceContext(unitName="puName")
EntityManager em;*

and make sure that EntityManager must be registered...

Answer (score 1):

try `@PersistenceContext` instead of `@Autowired`